# How to delete duplicate value in one column based on a string value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, duplicates

I have a Dataframe that has duplicate Name values. But, I only want to keep the duplicate value that has a Team value set to "TOT":

```
Name        Team        Games
Trevor      SAC         32
Trevor      TOT         50
Trevor      POR         18
Kyle        MEM         59
LeMarcus    SAS         43
Jordan      TOT         50
Jordan      MIN         35
Jordan      ATL         15
Will        DEN         53
```

How do I delete a duplicate value in one column based on a string value in another column?

I would want an output like this:

```
Name        Team        Games
Trevor      TOT         50
Kyle        MEM         59
LeMarcus    SAS         43
Jordan      TOT         50
Will        DEN         53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do use duplicated:

```
df.loc[~(df.Name.duplicated(keep=False) & df.Team.ne('TOT'))]
```

Or you can use a groupby and then filter.

```
(
    df.groupby('Name',sort=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x if len(x)==1 else x.loc[x.Team.eq('TOT')])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

    Name        Team    Games
0   Trevor      TOT     50
1   Kyle        MEM     59
2   LeMarcus    SAS     43
3   Jordan      TOT     50
4   Will        DEN     53
```

Comment: I tried the groupby solution and that worked for me but I have trouble understanding it. Can you explain in layman's term the process?

Answer (score 0):

You can stack two dataframes, where one dataframe has rows (unique per `Name`) where `Team == 'TOT'`, and the other has players who don't have any rows where `Team == 'TOT'`, finally sorting by the index to restore the initial ordering.

```
pd.concat([
  df[df.Team=='TOT'].drop_duplicates('Name'), 
  df[~df.Name.isin(df.Name[df.Team=='TOT'])]
]).sort_index()

       Name Team  Games
1    Trevor  TOT     50
3      Kyle  MEM     59
4  LeMarcus  SAS     43
5    Jordan  TOT     50
8      Will  DEN     53
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a side dataframe to help filter out the rows you do not need:

```
SideDataFrame = df.duplicated('name', keep = False)

FilteredDataFrame = pd.concat([df[SideDataFrame == False, df[(SideDataFrame == True) & (df.name == 'TOT')]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
df.loc[(df['Team'] =='TOT')].append(df[df.groupby('Name').Name.transform(len) == 1]).sort_index()
```